# How to Connect Nakama Client (on unity) to a linux VM instance

Tags: unity-game-engine, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, cockroachdb, nakama

i’ve created an instance that runs on a linux virtual matchine
i’ve also installed cockroachdb and nakama on that vm and started the node and nakama server there
i’m using oracle cloud infrastructure, i added security list to it to be able to access it through internet and now when try access it through the internet it shos me my server like this :
and now i dont know to to connect to this ???
i have the client in using and it doesn’t connect to it

and when i run it, it shows me this error

i also added the nakama port 7350, and the dashboard 7351 to the security list to have access to them through oci cloud and now the dashboard looks like this

where is the issue and how should i fix it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using platform images, both Linux and Windows come with the OS firewall activated and allow very few services.

Open the ports on the OS firewall and try again.